# PublicAccess permissions not working in Umbraco 6

Tags: permissions, umbraco

I am trying to display a table listing some documents (nodes) to the users. Those documents are protected using role permissions (right click > Public Access > Role Permissions) and I want to show only those to which this user has access.

After checking here and there, I've seen that there isn't any "Node.Permissions" way, so you have to go through Access.HasAccess().

I have used that, and I have set the permissions, but when I use the method it returns always true. What am I doing wrong?

This is the code to build the list of nodes, which works perfectly:

```
    public static List<Node> GetAllNodeChildrenRecursively(int nodeId, string typeName)
    {
        var node = new Node(nodeId);
        var lstNodes = new List<Node>();
        foreach (Node childNode in node.Children)
        {
                var child = childNode;
                if (child.NodeTypeAlias == typeName)
                {
                    lstNodes.Add(childNode);
                }

                if (child.Children.Count > 0)
                {
                    lstNodes.AddRange(GetAllNodeChildrenRecursively(childNode.Id, typeName));
                }
        }
        return lstNodes;
    }
```

This is the code to remove those I haven't access to:

```
        var availableNodes = new List<Node>();
        foreach(Node n in nodes)
        {
            if(Access.HasAccces(n.Id, memberId))
            {
                availableNodes.Add(n);
            }
        }
        return availableNodes;
```

Well, Access.HasAccess returns always true, and the member I am using to test is not part of the MemberGroup that has access to that node. Am I setting permissions wrong or not checking it properly or what?

I'm lost.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you should use the following method:

*There are a few different calls to HasAccess so it might depend on your version of Umbraco as well.

```
var availableNodes = new List<Node>();
        try
        {
            //this will throw an argument exception if there is not a current user logged in
            var currentMember = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser();

            foreach (Node n in retVal)
            {
                if (Access.HasAccess(n.Id, n.Path, currentMember))
                {
                    availableNodes.Add(n);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(ArgumentException e)
        {
            //do something when there is not a logged in member
        }
        return availableNodes;
```